# I was just looking template and found this code in my book and this is showing segmantation fault?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, runtime-error

This code gives the segmantation fault
Is the constructor called when assigning array to template specifically in this program?
Please explain in detail
if the constructor is called why is segmantation fault?
if not called isn't this the syntax error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int size=3;
template<class T>
class vector{
    T *v;
    public:
    vector(){
        v = new T[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            v[i]=0;
        }
    }
    vector(T *a){
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            v[i]=a[i];
        }
    }
    T operator*(vector &v){
        T sum=0;
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            sum+=this->v[i]*v.v[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
    void display(){
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            cout << v[i] <<"\t";
        }
    }

};
int main()
{
    int x[3]={1,3,5};
    int y[3]={2,4,6};
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    v1=x;
    v2=y;
    v1.display();
    cout<<endl;
    v2.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This [doesn't even compile](https://godbolt.org/z/tJrkUQ)  because of `using namespace std;`. Seems like a bad book.

Comment: `using namespace std;` + `class vector` is reason enough to never open the book again

Comment: First *terrible* name for a class, *especially* when slurping in the entire `std` namespace, [which you shouldn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). By all means, tell us the name of the book and author. I need to know if I have any of that trash in my library.

Comment: If this is code from a book, I suggest you re-purpose the book for something other than learning C++.

Comment: The constructor from `T*` does not allocate any memory. So `v` is not a valid memory address and dereferencing it by `v[i]` and assigning to it causes the segfault.

Comment: please post real code, this cannot cause a segfault, because it does [not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c0Y3YMFJtJtbtnB7)

Comment: After I cleaned up the 50 errors and warnings, and added `v = new T[Xsize];` to the second constructor that wasn't initializing `v`, it worked for me.  Is this one of those books that teaches by giving bad code and the student has to correct the code so that it works?  I recommend turning on all warnings, and using a debugger.

Comment: @Sandeep Here's a half-hearted attempt at salvaging what can be salvaged from that code: https://godbolt.org/z/Dm2Gwp It should give you a slightly better base for your explorations. It requires C++17 so I hope you have a C++17 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from all the awful code, there's a problem with:

```
int x[3]={1,3,5};
...
vector<int> v1(x);
```

which calls:

```
template<class T>
class vector{
    T *v;
    ...
    public:
    vector(T *a){
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            v[i]=a[i];
        }
    }
    ...
```

because pointer `v` hasn't been assigned any memory.
So the first time through the `for` loop: `v[0] = a[0];` will cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: sorry for the wrong code actually there's only vector<int> v1; and it's causing same error

Comment: @SandeepAcharya It doesn't matter. The same problematic constructor is still fired during the conversion operation of `v1 = x;` (and `v2 = y`). Like it or not, that constructor is broken.

Comment: Thank you for that but why does assignment operator even calls the constructor?

Comment: @SandeepAcharya There is no assignment operator=() defined so you'll get the default which is wrong too.